# A combinatorial identity involving square of central binomial coefficient.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

While solving a problem  I came across the following interesting identity, valid by numerical evidence:
$$
S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n\left (-\frac14\right)^k\binom {2k}k^2\frac1 {1-2k}\binom {n+k-2}{2k-2}=\begin {cases}\displaystyle 
\left [ \left (\frac14\right)^m\binom {2m}m\frac1 {1-2m}\right]^2,& n=2m;\\
0,& n=2m+1.
\end{cases}\tag1 $$
Is there a simple way to prove it?

---

From WA I know:
$$S_n=\frac {(1-(-1)^n)\Gamma^2 (\frac {n-1}2)}{8\pi\Gamma^2 (\frac {n+2}2)}\tag2 $$
Obviously (2) evaluates to 0 for odd $n $. For $n=2m$ the expression gives
$$S_{2m}=\frac {\Gamma^2 (m-\frac12)}{4\pi\Gamma^2 (m+1)}=\frac {\left [\frac {(2m-2)!}{(m-1)!}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4^{m-1}}\right]^2}{4\pi (m!)^2}\\
=4\left [\frac1 {4^{m}}\frac{m} {(2m)(2m-1)}\frac {(2m)!}{m!m!}\right]^2
=\left [\frac1 {4^{m}}\frac{1} {2m-1}\binom {2m}{m}\right]^2,$$
also in agreement with (1).

However I still wonder how the result can be obtained without resorting to computer help.

Comment: Have you tried Zeilberger's algorithm?

Comment: @PeterTaylor No. I am not experienced in this technique and will be very thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from (the contribution from $k=0$  is zero owing to the third
binomial coefficient)

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k
{2k\choose k}^2 \frac{1}{1-2k} {n+k-2\choose 2k-2}$$

we seek to show that this is zero when $n\gt 1$ is odd and

$$\left[\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^m 
{2m\choose m} \frac{1}{1-2m}\right]^2$$

when $n=2m$ is even.

We observe that with $k\ge 1$

$${2k\choose k} \frac{1}{1-2k} {n+k-2\choose 2k-2}
= 2 {2k-1\choose k-1} \frac{1}{1-2k} {n+k-2\choose 2k-2}
\\ = -2 {2k-2\choose k-1} \frac{1}{k} {n+k-2\choose 2k-2}
= -\frac{2}{k} \frac{(n+k-2)!}{(k-1)!^2 \times (n-k)!}
\\ = -\frac{2}{k} {n+k-2\choose k-1} {n-1\choose k-1}
= -\frac{2}{n} {n\choose k} {n+k-2\choose k-1}.$$

We get for our sum

$$-\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 
{n\choose k} \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^k
{2k\choose k}
{n+k-2\choose k-1}
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 
{n\choose k} {-1/2\choose k}
{n+k-2\choose n-1}
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-2} \sum_{k=1}^n 
{n\choose k} {-1/2\choose k} (1+z)^k.$$

The value $k=0$ contributes zero:

$$-\frac{2}{n} \times 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w} (1+w)^{-1/2}
[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-2} \sum_{k=0}^n 
{n\choose k} \frac{1}{w^k} (1+z)^k
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} \times 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w} (1+w)^{-1/2}
[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-2} (1+(1+z)/w)^n
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} \times 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{-1/2}
[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-2} (1+w+z)^n
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} \times 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} (1+w)^{-1/2}
[z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{n-2} 
\sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q} (1+w)^q z^{n-q}
\\ = -\frac{2}{n} \times 
\sum_{q=1}^n {n\choose q} {q-1/2\choose n} 
{n-2\choose q-1}.$$

Now observe  that with  $q\lt n$ (third  binomial coefficient  is zero
when $q=n$)

$${q-1/2\choose n} = \frac{1}{n!} (q-1/2)^\underline{n}
= \frac{1}{n!} \prod_{p=0}^{q-1} (q-1/2-p)
\prod_{p=q}^{n-1} (q-1/2-p)
\\ = \frac{1}{n! \times 2^n} \prod_{p=0}^{q-1} (2q-1-2p)
\prod_{p=q}^{n-1} (2q-1-2p)
\\ = \frac{1}{n! \times 2^n} 
\frac{(2q-1)!}{(q-1)! \times 2^{q-1}}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-1-q} (-1-2p)
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{n-q}}{n! \times 2^n} 
\frac{(2q-1)!}{(q-1)! \times 2^{q-1}}
\frac{(2n-1-2q)!}{(n-1-q)! \times 2^{n-1-q}}
\\= \frac{(-1)^{n-q}}{2^{2n-2}}
{n\choose q}^{-1} {2q-1\choose q-1} {2n-1-2q\choose n-q}.$$

We get for our sum

$$-\frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} \times 
\sum_{q=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{n-q} 
{2q-1\choose q-1} {2n-1-2q\choose n-q}
{n-2\choose q-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} \times 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-2-q} 
{2q+1\choose q} {2n-3-2q\choose n-q-1}.$$

This becomes

$$\frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} \times [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-3}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-2-q} 
{2q+1\choose q} z^q (1+z)^{-2q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1+w}{w} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-3}
\\ \times 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-2-q} 
\frac{1}{w^{q}} (1+w)^{2q} z^q (1+z)^{-2q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1+w}{w} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)^{2n-3}
\left(\frac{z(1+w)^2}{w(1+z)^2}-1\right)^{n-2}
\\ = \frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1+w}{w^{n-1}} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)
\left(z(1+w)^2-w(1+z)^2\right)^{n-2}
\\ = \frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} 
\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1+w}{w^{n-1}} [z^{n-1}] (1+z)
(z-w)^{n-2} (1-wz)^{n-2}.$$

The first piece in $z$ is

$$[z^{n-1}] (z-w)^{n-2} (1-wz)^{n-2}
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-2-q} w^{n-2-q}
{n-2\choose n-1-q} (-1)^{n-1-q} w^{n-1-q}
\\ = - \sum_{q=1}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} {n-2\choose q-1}
w^{2n-3-2q}.$$

Here we require

$$([w^{n-2}] + [w^{n-3}]) w^{2n-3-2q}$$

We get  $q=(n-1)/2$ in the first  case and $q=n/2$ in  the second.  As
this is a pair of an integer  and a fraction clearly only one of these
extractors can return a non-zero value.

The second piece in $z$ is

$$[z^{n-2}] (z-w)^{n-2} (1-wz)^{n-2}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} (-1)^{n-2-q} w^{n-2-q}
{n-2\choose n-2-q} (-1)^{n-2-q} w^{n-2-q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose q} {n-2\choose q}
w^{2n-4-2q}.$$

Solving for $q$ again we require

$$([w^{n-2}] + [w^{n-3}]) w^{2n-4-2q}$$

getting  $q=n/2-1$ and  $q=(n-1)/2.$

Supposing that $n$ is odd i.e.  $n=2m+1$ we thus have

$$-{2m-1\choose m} {2m-1\choose m-1} +
{2m-1\choose m} {2m-1\choose m} = 0,$$

and we have proved the second part of the claim.
On the other hand with $n=2m$ even we collect

$$-{2m-2\choose m} {2m-2\choose m-1}
+ {2m-2\choose m-1} {2m-2\choose m-1}
\\ = {2m-2\choose m-1}^2 \left(1 - \frac{m-1}{m}\right)
= \frac{m^2} {(2m-1)^2} {2m-1\choose m}^2 
\frac{1}{m}
\\ = \frac{m^2} {(2m-1)^2} \frac{m^2}{(2m)^2} {2m\choose m}^2 
\frac{1}{m}
= \frac{1}{4} \frac{m} {(2m-1)^2}  {2m\choose m}^2.$$

Restoring the factor in front we obtain

$$\frac{1}{n \times 2^{2n-3}} 
\frac{1}{4} \frac{m} {(2m-1)^2}  {2m\choose m}^2
= \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \frac{1} {(2m-1)^2}  {2m\choose m}^2
\\ = \frac{1}{2^{4m}} \frac{1} {(1-2m)^2}  {2m\choose m}^2$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\left[\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^m 
{2m\choose m} \frac{1}{1-2m}\right]^2}$$

as was to be shown.

Comment: The $\times$, the $Res_{w=0}$ and $[z^{n-1}]$ are all special notations, aren't they?

Comment: Wikipedia has an entry on [extracting coefficients of formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Extracting_coefficients) and an entry on [complex residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)).

Comment: So the second is the residue and the third is the coefficient extraction operator. And the $times$ is just a regular multiplication?

Comment: Yes it is. There is an implicit parenthesis around everything that follows the times symbol which extends to the end of a multiline formula, thereby enforcing precedence. Also sometimes used for readability.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Impressive and instructive derivation. Verified. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the credit. The factorizations of ${q-1/2\choose n}$ and of $z(1+w)^2-w(1+z)^2$ were quite remarkable indeed, appearing in the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

In general, definite sums of binomial expressions (technically, *hypergeometric terms*) can be tackled by a technique called Zeilberger's algorithm. See the book $A = B$ by Petkovšek, Wilf, and Zeilberger. Used to be available legally online in PDF, and maybe still is somewhere.

The actual algorithm is complicated enough that it's better to implement it in a CAS than work it through by hand except in really trivial cases, but knowing its existence allows you to throw the sum at a CAS which implements it. In particular, Wolfram Alpha gave me

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1} \frac{1}{(-4)^k (1 - 2k)} \binom{2k}{k}^2 \binom{2m+1+k-2}{2k-2} = \frac{\pi}{4\Gamma(1-m)^2 \Gamma\left(m+\frac32\right)^2}$$

which can be un-substituted to give

$$\sum_k \frac{1}{(-4)^k(1-2k)} \binom{2k}k^2 \binom{n+k-2}{2k-2} = \frac{\pi}{4\Gamma\left(\frac{3-n}2\right)^2 \Gamma\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^2}$$

which looks like it's a good way towards your target. It also points up an exception to your case analysis: when $n=1$ the sum is non-zero.

Comment: Thank yo very much. I have obtained with WA the result $$S_n=\frac{(1+(-1)^n)\Gamma^2(\frac{n-1}2)}{8\pi\Gamma^2(\frac{n+2}2)}$$ and still wonder if a human being is able to obtain the result without resorting to the computer help. But at least I know now the name of technique behind. Note the result is 0 for $n=1$ as well.

Comment: Zeilberger's algorithm can be done by hand, but it's tedious and error-prone. A homemade implementation could print the intermediate steps. For $n=1$ I evaluate the sum as $$\binom 00^2 \binom{-1}{-2} + \left(-\frac14\right) \binom 21^2 \frac1{1-2}\binom 00 =0+1$$

Comment: I agree with WA definition $$\binom{-1}{-2}=-1.$$ Then the sum evaluates to 0.